# How can I prevent my question from being closed?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Sometimes I post a question on https://stackoverflow.com and somebody thinks my question is unclear. They may vote to close my question (e.g., this question: [Does TensorFlow support to save the initial hyper-parameter configuration automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48776384/does-tensorflow-support-to-save-the-initial-hyper-parameter-configuration-automa)). How can I prevent my question from getting closed? I think users should post a comment to ask for clarification or explain how to improve my question.

Comment: You'd try to improve your question to make it clearer. Listen to feedback given, if any. Make sure you read and understand all of [ask] and the posts it links to.

Comment: Please keep meta-comments outside the question. Regardless whether it should or should not be closed, that is not the way you should address this.

Comment: @usr2564301 of course, but those guys didn't give any reasons.

Comment: They did vote for *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.*

Comment: @rene, I think those guys may not understand my question. As you can see in that post, some other experts can understand my question.

Comment: Your question is not closed. There's only one unclear close vote on your question. It seems you're overreacting a bit.

Comment: Actually, I didn't think people were able to see close votes on their questions without sufficient reputation, other than possible duplicate votes. Are you referring to the downvotes?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, in fact, I don't understand why those guys want to close or downvote some questions. I think they could provide advice to help improve those questions. If they thought the question was not described clearly, they may provide where it is.

Comment: @rene, I added that bolded sentence because I had seen that `close` vote. But I'm not sure what is not clear.

Comment: if anything, don't change this into a [request to make comments on down (or close votes) mandatory](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s/357437#357437) that will not end well.

Comment: @rene, I think it would be better to write their reasons or comments when those guys are downvoting or closing the question. Purely downvote or close operations don't have any help for improving the quality of the questions. And if one question was downvoted, other experts may not want to open it, I guess.

Comment: I'm not going to leave a comment every time I cast a close or downvote, specially if that leads to yet another fruitless discussion about *my question is wrongfully closed/down voted*.

Comment: @mining maybe it would better, but SO has no mechanism for charging for such personalized, entended explanations and, anyway, it would be very expensive.

Comment: @rene BUT MY QUESTION IS A SPECIAL CASE!

Comment: @mining maybe not seeing this as a fight would be helpful? Coming into that discussion with the intent to 'combat' will VERY RARELY lead to a fruitful conversation....

Comment: @Patrice, you are right, `oppose` or `argue against` may be better.

Comment: @mining I for one prefer to approach these with neutral words. Like 'Discuss', 'review', 'clarify' etc. The other words make it look like you see yourself as right and won't be willing to consider another point of view. May not be your case but god knows this is a trend on Meta.

Comment: @Patrice, thanks. Your suggestions are valuable. I welcome and appreciate for any comments or suggestions. In fact, I also don't like to impose any of my thoughts/viewpoints/opinions on others, and vice versa. In terms of `god`, it seems there are many gods in this world. If god helps, I hope he/she can also teach his/her people to respect others and be easy-going. Then the world may be more peaceful, I think.

Answer (score 7):

Your question body is unclear.

> We need to run the designed networks many times for better performance and it would be better to record our experiments we have run.

Okay, that is good for context

> Maybe it could be good to provide to record these hyper-parameter configuration automatically by the tensorflow execution engine.

Yes, that would probably be very good. But it sounds as a feature request for the tensorflow execution engine, not as something extremely relevant for the question at hand.

> For example, I record by set different directory name for the log directory as:
>
> ```
>  log_lr_0.001_theta_0.1_alpha_0.1
>  log_lr_0.01_theta_0.01_alpha_0.02
>  ....
> ```

I don't know a single thing about tensorflow but I assume you start this somewhere, either on a commandprompt, GUI tool or a webinterface, where you provide or control that log setting. Where is it? What are the steps you followed? What did you enter where?

What is missing is how you attempted to achieve what you need. Did you look for an API, what did you learn from the manual, what approach did you try to conquer the issue? Did you use bash/powershell? AutoIt? Keyboard recording? SED? awk?

> Are there any automatic ways to help this?

For almost everything there is some automatic way. So the answer is yes.

> In addition, it would be better that when we start a new tensorflow training instance, a new port will be allocated and a new tensorboard is started and shows its learning state.

What? Did you just start a new question? Or is this an additional requirement for your automatic way? Or is this missing info in your log file? It would be easier if you keep it to a single question per post. That guarantees the answers can be concise as well.

Based on my analysis of your question, I think your question can use some editorial love. I support the close vote, if it was not for unclear, then it should be for too broad.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your analysis and thoughts on this question! For the last `in addition`, I agree that should be deleted. I thought the former description may be easily understood by the `tensorflow` community. Thus I just gave one tag of `tensorflow`. Before I started this question, I may think the readers may have some background or experience in this area. It is true that I should give more details on my question.

Comment: As an understander of the TensorFlow context, I still find the question too broad. The question is missing many important details of what you currently have. Without code, we can't tell which TensorFlow API you are mostly based on (could be on top of the Estimator API, Keras, or your own boilerplate), which also means that a good answer would have to fill in that blank. Phrasing it as "Are there any automatic ways to help this?" doesn't help here either: if TensorFlow does not provide an upfront solution to that, you are just requesting us to build that for you.

Comment: @E_net4, thanks a lot for comments! Maybe I thought that I had described the question clearly and believed that anybody with experience in TensorFlow would understand what I had written. In fact, to make it clear, I wrote that small example in that post to help the readers to understand my question. In fact, for that question, I'm not sure what code I should post. I had that question just because I wondered if there is any APIs or tools to do that work to help the programmers to manage those experimental logs produced when adjusting the hyper-parameters.

Comment: @mining Again, I roughly understood the question. I've worked with TensorFlow myself and understand the need for hyperparameter searching. However, I can imagine a wide variety of ways to achieve that, especially without a baseline in the question to work from (e.g. a minimalist code that takes the data and trains a simple linear classifier). Once you ask explicitly _"if there are any APIs or tools to do that work"_, it becomes a request for an off-site resource, which is off-topic.

Comment: @E_net4, understood, thanks a lot! If convenient, could you please help check if this question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48817330/how-to-get-the-errors-for-some-certain-layers-in-tensorflow" was correctly posted? Still no answers till now. I'm not sure if I described the question clearly.